# Chrome thinks 99,999 is drastically different than 100,000

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just ran into a very interesting issue when someone posted a jsperf benchmark that conflicted with a previous, nearly identical, benchmark I ran.

Chrome does something *drastically* different between these two lines:

```
new Array(99999);  // jsperf ~50,000 ops/sec
new Array(100000); // jsperf ~1,700,000 ops/sec
```

benchmarks: http://jsperf.com/newarrayassign/2

I was wondering if anyone has any clue as to what's going on here!

(To clarify, I'm looking for some low-level details on the V8 internals, such as it's using a different data structure with one vs the other and what those structures are)

Comment: what if you do the tests in the opposite order?

Comment: maby it's becouse its a number more and that it handles numbers of 6 digites diferent?

Comment: @gar_onn - if that were the case, the switch would be at `65,536` or `16,777,216` or some other power of 2

Comment: One should have really thought such a threshold would be at some more canonical size. Pretty ugly that it's 100000 rather than 65536 or 131072 or 98304!

Comment: @leftaroundabout - 98,304?  Really?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes I know, but why?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just because this sounded pretty interesting, I searched through the V8 codebase for a static defined as 100000, and I found [this `kInitialMaxFastElementArray` var](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2.5.9.22/src/objects.h#L1688), which is the subsequently used in the [builtin `ArrayConstructInitializeElements` function](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2.5.9.22/src/builtins.cc#L211) function. While I'm not a c programmer and don't know the nitty-gritty here, you can see that it's using an `if` loop to determine if it's smaller than 100,000, and `return`ing at different points based on that.

Comment: Thank you :)  What it looks like to me is that Chrome is actually doing a pointer memory-allocation for all arrays < 100,000 whereas it's not allocating anything >= 100,000.  This makes sense in the benchmarks because the declaration only is ___far___ faster, but then using that array is slower than using the 99,999 array.

Comment: @CodyGray - Gee whiz man, this is a 10 year old question, best practices weren't quite set up back then. Spent a few minutes and updated the answer to point to github, hopefully it's more stable. I have no idea what I meant by `if` loop above... probably should have said "logic in an if statement".

Comment: I think we had the same rule regarding "link-only" answers going back 10 years, as the problem of "link rot" was well known even back then. Either way, thanks for putting in some effort on this. Apparently, it's been useful to others throughout the years, so it's reasonable to assume that it will continue to be useful, once updated. I've deleted my original comment as obsolete, along with a couple of others saying that the links are dead.

Answer (score 10):

Well, there always is some threshold number when you design algorithms that adapt to the size of data (for example [SharePoint changes the way it works when you add 1000 items to a list](http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1395432.htm)). So, the guess would be that you have found the actual number and the performance differs, as different data structures or algorithms are used.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what operating system you're using, but if this is Linux, I'd suspect that Chrome (i.e. `malloc`) is allocating memory from a program-managed heap (size determined using the `sbrk` system call, and the free lists are managed by the C standard library), but when you reach a certain size threshold, it switches to using `mmap` to ask the kernel to allocate large chunks of memory that don't interfere with the `sbrk`-managed heap.

[Doug Lea](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) describes how `malloc` works in the GNU C Library, better than I could. He wrote it.

---

Or maybe 100000 hits some kind of magic threshold for the amount of space needed that it triggers the garbage collector more frequently when trying to allocate memory.